# Sony Spresense built-in app not found

Tags: ubuntu, spresense

Spresense SDK チュートリアルの examples/hello をチュートリアルの手順にしたがって試してみました。「1.4. Spresense メインボードへのイメージのロード」の図３にあるように、loadに成功し、rebootまでの表示が出ました（サイズは154176 bytes と、図３の表示とは若干異なります）。updater# sync という表示も出ています。

ところが、minicom で繋いで、hello と入力しても、command not found となり、help で見ても、Builtin Apps: には何のエントリーもありません。Nuttxのversionは7.22です。

また、チュートリアルでは、examplesのディレクトリはsdkの下にあるように書かれていましたが、
ダウンロードしたものでは、sdkと同じ階層にありました(それで mv しました）。

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense.git
```

のダウンロードも、なぜか２回行わないと、spresenseのディレクトリが現れませんでした。

どう対処すれば良いでしょうか？　ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

外しているかもしれませんが、「Spresense SDK チュートリアル」の ”1.3. Spresense メインボードへのブートローダーのインストール” を行いましたか？

NuttX が正しくインストールされているならば、

```
NuttShell (NSH)
nsh>
```

のコマンドプロンプトが出るはずです。おぼろげな記憶で不確かですが、ブートローダをインストールしていないと、"updater#" のコマンドプロンプトが出ていたように思います。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。ブートローダはインストールしていて、minicomで接続した時、nsh> のプロンプトが出ています。versionもWarning で 指定されているものに合わせています。そもそもnuttx.spkがディレクトリのどこに保存されるのかもわかっていない状況です。

Comment: なるほど。質問の内容をあらためて見ると、ビルドした "nuttx.spk" が "spresense/sdk"になく、"spresense"ディレクトリに作成されているということのようですね。だとすると環境の問題かな…。答えになっておらずスイマセン。

Comment: ”examples” ディレクトリを "sdk" ディレクトリに移してビルドしてみたら、普通にビルドできるのですね。出来上がった nuttx.spk をSPRESENSEに焼き込んでみたら、同じ症状になりました。”examples” を "sdk" ディレクトリに移動したのが問題なのだと思います。 "spresense/sdk/examples"でなく、"spresense/examples" にして手順通りビルドしてみたらうまくいくと思います。試してみてください。

Comment: 再度のご回答、ありがとうございます。無事、アプリをロードできました。助かりました。チュートリアルで、$ tools/config.py examples/hello とあったので、examplesはsdkのディレクトリにないといけないと思い、mvしていました。config.py の中で、上のディレクトリを見に行っていたのですね。余計なことをしていました。